# Text sharing not working as expected

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, sharing

```
protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Title";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Description";         
    e.Request.Data.SetText("Description");
}
```

I am sharing my app link link this.

**What I expect it to do:**

When sharing with text message app

Message: Description

When sharing with email app

Subject: Title

Message: Description

**What it is doing:**

When sharing with text message app

Message: Title Description

When sharing with email app

Subject: Title

Message: Description

I want to share only description when user share using message. But it is appending title with it also.

Comment: Each share target gets to decide how it wants to deal with the data.

Comment: So in short it is not possible to handle?